# What explains the asymmetry here?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The image operation distributes over unions:

$$f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$$

but about intersections we can only say that

$$f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$$

unless $f$ is injective. Where does this asymmetry arise from?

Answer (score 15):

The asymmetry arises because functions themselves are defined asymmetrically.

A function $f$ is defined so that:

- for all $x$ in the domain there exists a unique $y$ in the image such that $f(x)=y$

In order for the definition to be symmetric we'd also need

- for all $y$ in the image there exists a unique $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$

The second point is exactly the definition of injectivity. (The first point is well-definedness.) Injectivity is equivalent to distributivity over intersections (see the other answers to this question).

The fact that all functions are well-defined corresponds with the distributivity over unions; the fact that *not* all functions are injective corresponds with the (lack of) distributivity over intersections: those functions which do distribute over all intersections are injective.

Comment: I started writing an identical answer, then got stuck whilst trying to clarify the "fact that all functions are well-defined corresponds with the distributivity over unions". How?

Comment: @pelotom 'Multivalued' functions, taken to mean maps $f:X\to \mathbb P Y \setminus\{\emptyset\}$ to non-empty sets still obey distributivity over unions.

Comment: @Clive, can you comment? How does well-definedness correspond to distributivity over unions?

Comment: @pelotom: Even with multivalued functions, you're still posing the question asymmetrically, in that you're splitting preimages (*A* vs. *B*) but not images (the various values of the multivalued function). To pose the question symmetrically, you'd have to allow the images to split the same way. For example, let *f* and *g* be multivalued functions. Then $(f \cup g)(A) = f(A) \cup g(A)$, but $(f \cap g)(A) \subseteq f(A) \cap g(A)$.

Comment: It seems that well-definedness has no effect on the distributivity of the image operation over unions or intersections. However it _does_ disrupt the distributivity of the _inverse_ image operation over intersections, i.e. for a "multivalued" function $f: X \rightarrow \mathcal P \left(Y\right) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$, define the inverse image of $A$ under $f$, $f^{-1}(A)$ as $\{ x \mid f(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset \}$. Then $f^{-1}(A \cup B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$ but $f^{-1}(A \cap B) \subseteq f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$, similarly to the asymmetry of the image operation.

Answer (score 4):

If $y\in f[A]\cup f[B]$, then $y$ must be the image under $f$ of something in $A$ or of something in $B$, i.e., of something in $A\cup B$. If $y\in f[A]\cap f[B]$, on the other hand, we know that $y$ is the image of some $a\in A$ **and** the image of $b\in B$, but there’s no reason to suppose that $a$ and $b$ are the same thing, or even that there is anything at all in $A\cap B$. Of course if $f$ is injective (one-to-one), then $a$ and $b$ **do** have to be the same thing, and in that case we get equality of $f[A\cap B]$ and $f[A]\cap f[B]$.

I’d say that the different behavior isn’t so much a matter of some inherent asymmetry between $\cup$ and $\cap$ as it is a matter of how these Boolean operations interact with arbitrary functions.

Comment: Thanks Brian, as I mentioned in my comment on Peter's answer, I understand the proof, I'm just wondering why there is the apparent asymmetry that the image operation distributes over unions but not intersections (in general).

Comment: @pelotom: I suspected that you did, but it seems to me that the reason that equality can fail in the case of $\cap$ really is about the only explanation; as I said in the addition that I just made to my answer, it’s the interaction with the function that does it, more than the Boolean operation itself.

Comment: @Peter: Not really, no. Given time I can usually work my way through relatively straightforward expository material, but it’s a great deal of work.

Answer (score 2):

If $f:X\to Y$, then $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ for each $A,B\subseteq X$ is equivalent to $f$ being *injective*, hence the discrepancy in general. Again $f(A\setminus B)=f(A)\setminus f(B)\iff\text{ injection }$, so when taking the complement of your first $\bigcup$ relation, the injectivity will be needed to get to the other expression.

Comment: I understand that $f$ being injective makes it an equivalence, but my question is why the apparent asymmetry of the situation? There are no qualifications on the first equation.

Comment: What do you mean by "asymmetry"?

Comment: It's really an aesthetic quality I'm noticing. $\cup$ and $\cap$ behave in most ways dually, so that you can get from one theorem about $\cup$ to another about $\cap$ by just "reversing everything". This seems like an exception to that rule. I'm thinking maybe it's due to the inherent asymmetry of the notion of function. Maybe this isn't a question that has a rigorous answer :)

Comment: @pelotom Well, but the duality works well with complements, not just reversing $\cap$ and $\cup$.

Comment: Another interesting thing is that with inverse image sets there is no asymmetry; $f^{-1}(A \cup B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$ and $f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$, no ifs ands or buts.

Comment: @pelotom Yes, the inverse image is really well behaved.

Comment: Intuitively I would expect that if somewhere there appears the qualification that $f$ must be injective to make an equality, then elsewhere $f$ must be surjective.

Answer (score 2):

(For fun,) I will express the asymmetry using the asymmetry between left and right adjoints in category theory. The main idea is that left adjoints commute with colimits (and unions are colimits in these categories) but not necessarily limits (and intersections are limits).

Let $f:C\to D$ be a function and let $\mathscr C$ be the category representing the partial order on the power set of $C$ given by inclusion. Similarly, construct $\mathscr D$. We have a functor $f:\mathscr C\to\mathscr D$ which assigns a set its image. The key is that it also "assigns" morphisms to morphisms, in other words it preserves order.

Define also $f^{-1}:\mathscr D\to\mathscr C$ by assigning a set its inverse image under $f$. This too is order-preserving, so it is a functor as well.

I claim $f$ is left-adjoint to $f^{-1}$. For any subset $S$ of $C$, we have both $S\subseteq f^{-1}fS$ and $ff^{-1}S\subseteq S$. To see the first, note that if $x\in S$, then $f(x)\in fS$. The second is tautological. Now, if $S\subseteq f^{-1}T$, then $f^{-1}fS\subseteq f^{-1}(ff^{-1}T)\subseteq f^{-1}T$. We just showed that the inclusion $S\subseteq f^{-1}fS$ is a universal arrow to $f^{-1}$ from $S$. The family of such arrows is clearly a natural transformation from the identity functor on $\mathscr C$ to the composite functor $f^{-1}f$. Therefore, $f\dashv f^{-1}$.

Since left adjoints commute with colimits, and union is a colimit in $\mathscr C$, we have $f(S\cup T)=f(S)\cup f(T)$. Dually, right adjoints commute with limits, but $f$ is not automatically a right adjoint. So, we cannot just say $f(S\cap T)=f(S)\cap f(T)$. In fact,

**Proposition.** *If $f:C\to D$ induces a right adjoint $f:\mathscr C\to\mathscr D$, then $f$ is injective.*
*Proof*. Let $g:\mathscr D\to\mathscr C$ be a functor such that if $S\subseteq D$ and $T\subseteq C$, $gS\subseteq T$ if and only if $S\subseteq fT$.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $x,y\in C$ are distinct elements such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Let $T=\{x\}$ and let $S=\{f(x)\}$. Then $gS\subseteq\{x\}$. Similarly $gS\subseteq\{y\}$ by setting $T=\{y\}$. Thus $gS=\emptyset$. In particular, $gS\subseteq C\setminus f^{-1}(f(x))$. Therefore, $S\subseteq D\setminus \{f(x)\}$, a contradiction. $\square$